# Rails SQLite 3 duplicate column error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to install Active Admin, which is a Ruby on Rails framework for administrator dashboard for websites. However everything went fine in installation when trying to rake db:migrate I get the following error.

```
rake db:migrate 

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "admin_users" ADD "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:329:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
........................
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this has been a commonly reported [issue](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/753).

Running the ActiveAdmin installer is most likely creating a migration file which conflicts with your existing database structure.

Try commenting out the line in the migration file which creates the email column, as this appears to be where the conflict is residing. Then try running `rake db:migrate` once more.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

That might happen when you have a duplicated migration file for active admin, find and delete it.

It seems duplication might be on some lines, open `db/migrate` and look for the line/s that is trying to create duplicated columns.